# Error in $ rosmake rgbdslam with ros-electric

Tags: slam, navigation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using ros-electric. When I build rgbdslam package in ros.

$ rosmake rgbdslam.

I got the error,

/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/rgbdslam.dir/src/openni_listener.o: in function OpenNIListener::processNode(Node*):openni_listener.cpp(.text+0x6fd4): error: undefined reference to 'clock_gettime'

Anybody have idea about this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/40416/error-in-$-rosmake-rgbdslam-with-ros-electric/) by [chris_chris](https://answers.ros.org/users/2965/chris_chris/) on ROS Answers with karma: 84 on 2012-08-02

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Add -lrt to the set of linked libraries in CMakeLists.txt

---

Originally posted by [Sudhan](https://answers.ros.org/users/1685/sudhan/) with karma: 171 on 2012-08-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I ever have similar problems.

Try to find header file that 'clock_gettime' needs,and add to openni_listener.cpp

---

Originally posted by [pig's head](https://answers.ros.org/users/2932/pig%27s-head/) with karma: 43 on 2012-08-02

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1